# Nginx Permission denied

Tags: centos, nginx, chmod

I am using Nginx to serve static files from server. Static file is located in root folder, `/server/cdn`. I give all permission to this folder with `sudo chmod 777 -R server` command. Also I changed the nginx configuration for server to serve static content from the given folder. I confirm that nginx is pointed to correct destination. But the problem is I get `403 permission denied`in the browser.

How can I fix this. Is it possible to give permission to other user to access content in root folder ?

Comment: Obviously you should have added your `nginx` configuration to your question...

Comment: And also the `nginx` logs. Please [edit] your question and add the `nginx` configuration and log files.

Comment: 403 errors can be caused by permission errors in the filesystem, but not only by filesystem permissions.  The nginx config can also return access permission erros when the visitor is not allowed to access the URL path.  The nginx config and log will help reveal this.

Comment: When I **should** be able to access a file but can't, ill-configured SELinux contexts or AppArmor could be the cause.